# how to get the value from two lists of different objects through jstl

Tags: java, web-applications

Below is two lists and each list having different objects

```
public String execute(){
    ArrayList<ViewCustomers> al = new Querydata().viewcust();
    list = al;

    ArrayList<bean> als = new Querydata().viewcust2();
    list1 = als;
}
```

And now below is my JSP file:

```
<tbody class="table table-hover">
    <d:iterator value="list" id="parent">
        <tr id="demo">
            <td><s:property value="#parent.cid"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="#parent.customername"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="#parent.cmobile"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="#parent.travelfrom"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="#parent.travelto"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="#parent.date"/></td>
            <d:iterator>
            <td>
                <select id="eid">
                    <option>select</option>
                    <option value='<s:property value="list1.EmpId"/>'></option>
                </select>                           
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name" value="" id=ename;>
            </td>
            </d:iterator>
            <td>
                <button type="button">GetEmployee</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </d:iterator>
</tbody>
```

I am not getting the values of the lists.

Comment: please include your expected output in your question

Comment: `<s:property value="list1.EmpId"/`, `#` missing here and just use  jstl `forEach`

Comment: i want all the values of two lists,one lists containing(Customer details)& another list containing(Employee Details) and i want to display the two lists of all values in a singe table only...